# How should we tag questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, 7-questions

The following tags might be too broad or too unspecific.

- [security](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) could be anything from contract-design to rpc-security or simply chosing weak passphrases
- [offline](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) could refer to cold-storage or offline signing of transactions
- [performance-optimization](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-optimization) is in my eyxes a total useless tag
- [architecture](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) seems like a meta-tag not really aiming at anything
- [data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) is also very broad and could be anything from data on-chain to wallet data, etc.

Are these tags too broad? How to deal with them? Please discuss.

Comment: What do you mean by "too broad?"  Perhaps you can clarify what problem you are seeing that might be in need of a solution. Tags aren't like questions that have too many answers. They are supposed to organize somewhat large swaths of subject matter so folks can find and follow their general interests. Some of those interests are more specific while others remain somewhat general. But the subject of [security] currently has 51 questions while the others only have 20 between them. Is it that they do not describe the question usefully? I'm not sure what folks are being asked to comment about here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have reviewed how these tags are used in practise to see if they can be broken down logically:

- [security](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) could possibly be broken down into [consensus](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consensus), [encryption](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption) / [cryptography](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography), [cold-storage](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-storage), *security best practises for node operation*, *security best practises for client/wallet usage*, *security best practises for contract design*, [attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attacks)
- <del>[offline](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) is in most (but not all) cases used a synonym for [cold-storage](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-storage)</del> (Joris: removed or retagged as [cold-storage](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-storage))
- <del>[performance-optimization](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-optimization) is used in different ways, can possible removed at all.</del> (5chdn: removed)
- [architecture](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) in both cases used to question design choices for the EVM & blockchain itself.
- [data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) is mostly used to discuss storing external data on the blockchain, and costs associated with transaction data: [data-on-chain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-on-chain), [gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gas) and [transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transactions) would cover this.
  For some of the usages I haven't found appropriate replacement tags yet; please edit!

Comment: This question does not match cold-storage but offline: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/87